# How do I make a single-task FILO background thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a bunch of threads that spawn somewhat arbitrarily. When they are racing each other, only the one that spawned last is relevant. The other threads can be thrown away or stopped. But I am not sure how to do that, so I have implemented a very basic counter that checks whether the thread is the latest spawned thread.

edit: I would like to be able to kill threads that are taking too long (as they are no longer necessary); probably not from within the threads themselves as they are busy doing something else.

This code works, it seems. But it doesn't feel robust. Can someone give me a hint toward a proper way to do this?

```java
class Main {
    private static volatile int latestThread = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            spawnThread();
        }
    }

    private static void spawnThread() {
        latestThread++;
        int thisThread = latestThread;
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (latestThread == thisThread) {
                // only the latest "active" thread is relevant
                System.out.println("I am the latest thread! " + thisThread);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

output:

```
I am the latest thread! 10
```

[code in replit.com](https://replit.com/@tiokr/LatestThread)

Comment: Why do you spin up all of these threads if only one of them is relevant? Especially for this sort of question -- where you're looking for the "proper" way to do something -- it's important to give enough information that we can understand what you're *really* trying to do, since that will help determine what the "proper" way to do it is.

Comment: That isn't thread safe unless you add the volatile keyword on the latestThread variable.

Comment: BTW, strictly speaking, there's no guarantee that the `if (latestThread == thisThread)` line will actually see the current value of `latestThread`, since `latestThread` will have been set by a different thread, with no happens-before relationship in most cases. So it's theoretically possible for a thread to *think* it's the latest thread even if it really isn't.

Comment: @ruakh The threads spawn from a user's interaction. But the user can interact multiple times per second, and the thread can take longer than a second (depends on what the program does).

Comment: @vakio: Instead of spawning a new thread each time the user interacts, maybe it would be more appropriate to submit tasks to a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: @vakio: Also, what should happen if a thread *is* the latest thread when it gets to the `if (latestThread == thisThread)` line, but then later another user interaction happens so it's no longer the latest thread?

Comment: If a thread is no longer the latest thread, it can be totally discarded. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: As a start, save the reference to the new thread to an AtomicReference or a ConcurrentHashMap so that you can interrupt it after necessary checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little research based on comments from everybody (thanks!) and `ThreadPoolExecutor` is *almost* what I need, but I want a pool with the total size of `1` (no queue) that kills the active thread once a new thread comes along, which is not allowed in a thread pool and not in line with what a ThreadPool is for. So instead, I came up with a reference to the active thread, and when a new thread comes a long it kills the old one, which seems to do what I want:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Interrupt {

    private static final AtomicInteger CURRENT_THREAD = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static Thread activeThread = new Thread(() -> {});

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            spawnThread();
            Thread.sleep(3);
        }
    }

    private static void spawnThread() {
        if (activeThread.isAlive()) {
            activeThread.interrupt();
        }
        activeThread = new Thread(() -> {
            int thisThread = CURRENT_THREAD.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(thisThread + " working");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(thisThread + " finished!");
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        });
        activeThread.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3 working
2 working
1 working
4 working
4 finished!
```

Comment: If you only want a maximum of 1 thread, are you absolutely sure you want to spawn a new thread each time?

Comment: Well, a task has to be performed and not on the main thread. Because the main thread is the GUI. So if I am not spawning a thread, I would have to inject the code into the one background thread somehow and keep it going... but that seems more complicated (?)

Comment: It sounds like what you basically want is a task queue and a single thread that takes tasks off the queue and executes them. Read up on the Executor framework and see the Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor() method.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a cleaner way of doing the same thing.. something like `future = executor.submit(task)` and then when a new task comes along: `future.cancel(true)` and submit the new task. I think that's the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I have another problem with user tasks not being able to be interrupted (if the user mistakenly made an infinite loop for example), which is why I was using more than one thread in the first place. But that is another question, and can probably be solved using ProcessBuilder and force-killing the process (only Windows seems to not want to kill the process).

Comment: Usually it's better not to stop tasks by "killing" them, but rather arrange for a clean way to signal to them that you want them to stop. (Thread interruption *can* be appropriate if the thread in question is actually going to be sitting in an interruptible call or will be regularly checking its interrupted() flag. Often it's better to have a separate flag/condition for that specific purpose.)

Answer (score 2):

ThreadPoolExecutor is almost what I need, specifically DiscardOldestPolicy. You can set the queue size to 1, so one thread is running and one thread is in the queue, and the oldest in the queue just gets shunted. Clean!

But it finishes two threads (not only the latest), which is not 100% what I was looking for. Although arguably good enough:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class DiscardOldest {

    private static int threadCounter = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int poolSize = 0;
        int maxPoolSize = 1;
        int queueSize = 1;
        long aliveTime = 1000;
        ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(queueSize);
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize, aliveTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue, new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy());

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            spawnThread(executor);
        }
    }

    private static void spawnThread(ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
      final int thisThread = threadCounter++;
      System.out.println(thisThread + " spawning");
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println(thisThread + " finished!");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
1 spawning
2 spawning
3 spawning
4 spawning
1 finished!
4 finished!
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relaying on an index, a born time could be set. If there's a younger thread (was born later) the thread should terminate its execution.

```
public class Last {
    private static volatile long latestThread = 0L;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            spawnThread(System.nanoTime(), i);
        }
    }

    private static void spawnThread(long startTime, int index) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            latestThread = startTime;
            long thisThread = startTime;
            boolean die = false;
            try {
                while (!die) {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    if (thisThread < latestThread) {
                        System.out.println(
                                index + ": I am not the latest thread :-(\n\t" + thisThread + "\n\t" + latestThread);
                        die = true;
                    } else if (thisThread == latestThread) {
                        System.out.println(
                                index + ": Yes! This is the latest thread!\n\t" + thisThread + "\n\t" + latestThread);
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                        System.out.println("Bye!");
                        die = true;
                    }
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0: I am not the latest thread :-(
    39667589567880
    39667602317461
2: Yes! This is the latest thread!
    39667602317461
    39667602317461
1: I am not the latest thread :-(
    39667602257160
    39667602317461
Bye!
```

Comment: That is definitely better than I have right now. It's interesting. I didn't specify it clearly in my question but I guess I am looking for a way to kill a thread from outside too. For example if it is taking too long (if Thread.sleep was longer), and it cannot kill itself.